# K&R exercise 2-5,error control may reach end of non-void function c

Tags: c

"Write the function any(s1,s2), which returns the first location in the string s1 where any character from the string s2 occurs, or -1 if s1 contains no characters from s2. 
When I compile my code, I get "control may reach end of non void function.which part causing the error，here’s my code:

```
int any(string a,string b){
    int i,j;
    int c = 0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){
        for(j=0;j<strlen(b);j++){
            if(b[j]==a[i]&&c==0){
                c = 1;
                return i;
                break;
            }  
        }
    }

    if(c==0) 
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: Do you have a question?

Comment: Incomplete code, but the last test my be false, then the control reaches the end of the function without returning any value; at least the compiler can't see that `c` is necessarily 0.

Comment: why do you need variable `c`? try to remove it. Also you don't need break after return

Comment: You might find the "error" goes away if you increase the compiler optimization level.    But a good solution anyway would be to remove `if(c==0)`.  If you are sure that `c` must be `0` at that point then the test is redundant anyway.

Answer (score 1):

You should start to learn to use **brackets**, this means that if you change this:

```
if(c==0) 
return -1;
```

To this:

```
if(c==0){
    return -1;
}
```

You will easy discover that there is no `return` if `C != 0`.

Another problem is here:

```
if(b[j]==a[i]&&c==0){
    c = 1;
    return i;
    break;
}
```

First you say `return i;` and then `break`, really?

Another thing is about `strlen` which is defined like this:

```
size_t strlen(const char * str){
    const char *s;
    for (s = str; *s; ++s) {}
    return(s - str);
}
```

`size_t` is `long unsigned int` which means that here:

```
for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++)
```

and here:

```
for(j=0;j<strlen(b);j++)
```

You are comparing an `int` with an `long unsigned int`.
This means that this line:

```
int i,j;
```

should be:

```
size_t i,j;
```

or:

```
long unsigned i,j;
```

So even if you fix that there are still some casts needed:

```
int any(string a,string b){
    size_t i,j;
    int c = 0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){
        for(j=0;j<strlen(b);j++){
            if(b[j]==a[i]&&c==0){
                c = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(c==1){
        return (int)i;
    }else{
        return (int)-1;
    }
}
```

Which means that you should reconsider writing in another way the whole program.

Maybe this will be ok for you:

```
size_t any(string a,string b){
    size_t i,j;
    int c = 0;
    for(i=0;i<strlen(a);i++){
        for(j=0;j<strlen(b);j++){
            if(b[j]==a[i]&&c==0){
                c = 1;
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if(c==1){
        return i;
    }else{
        return 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks，this is really helpful，I never notice that.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting the error because the compiler is not smart enough to realize that `c == 0` must be true if you get to the test. For the same reason, the test is completely unnecessary, so removing it and just returning `-1` at that point will fix the error.

You can simplify greatly by changing to:

```
int any(char * a, char * b){
    int i, j;

    for( i = 0; a[i]; ++i ) {
        for( j = 0; b[j]; ++j ) {
            if( b[j] == a[i] ) {
                return i;
            }  
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

This avoids the redundant test(s), avoids the need for your `c` variable altogether, and avoids the gratuitous and repeated calls to `strlen()`.

`typedef`ing `char *` as `string` is also in rather poor taste.

Probably over the top for this exercise, but by trading some memory efficiency for speed efficiency, you could set up an array as a lookup table and read the characters from `b` into it, and then step through `a` until you reach the end or get a match. This would require traversing the characters of `b` exactly once, and at most one full traversal through `a`, so you'd get a linear time algorithm rather than the quadratic time one you have now.

For instance:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int any(char * a, char * b);

int main(void)
{
    printf("'rifle', 'flog': %d\n", any("rifle", "flog"));
    printf("'pterodactyl', 'dint': %d\n", any("pterodactyl", "dint"));
    printf("'xyzzy', 'fish': %d\n", any("xyzzy", "fish"));

    return 0;
}

int any(char * a, char * b)
{
    int lookup[CHAR_MAX + 1] = {0};

    for ( int i = 0; b[i]; ++i ) {
        lookup[b[i]] += 1;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; a[i]; ++i ) {
        if ( lookup[a[i]] ) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

with output:

```
paul@horus:~/Documents/src/sandbox$ ./any
'rifle', 'flog': 2
'pterodactyl', 'dint': 1
'xyzzy', 'fish': -1
paul@horus:~/Documents/src/sandbox$
```